# Primefaces datatable duplicate "No records found" while doing column freeze for empty records

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am using primefaces `<p:datatable>` to freeze some of my columns.Everything is fine but when there are no records in  then it gives two "No records found" message.This is weird situation.Do anyone have come across this problem? Suggestions are welcome.I want only one "No records found " message.

```
        <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}" scrollable="true"
            frozenColumns="3" rows="10" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="     {CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" scrollHeight="400">

            <p:column width="50" headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.randomId}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column width="50" headerText="Year">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.randomYear}" />
            </p:column>
           //...................
</p:datatable>
```

[image: Custome message also don't work as they also appears twice.]

Comment: Have you tried PrimeFaces 8.6?

Comment: Kukeltje asks to post your PF version.

Comment: @Kukeltje PrimeFaces 8.6?

Comment: My primeface version is 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution to above problem.So, I manually overrided the css of second table generated by the above p:datatable.

My css is:

```
<style>
      .ui-datatable-frozenlayout-right .ui-datatable-empty-message td
     {
      display: none;
      //or visibility:hidden;
     } 
</style>
```